# Ghidra: Iterating over function's codeUnits returns only 1st instruction

Tags: ghidra, java

```
    public void run() throws Exception {
        var cp = currentProgram;
        var nsSymbols = ghidra.app.util.NamespaceUtils.getSymbols("myNameSpace", cp);
        var glNS = nsSymbols.get(0);
        var st = cp.getSymbolTable();
        var childs = st.getChildren(glNS);
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        println("Test");
        while (childs.hasNext())
        {
            var next = childs.next();
            var func = (Function)next.getObject();
            var body = func.getBody();
            var lbcu = cp.getListing().getCodeUnits(body, true);
            var i = 0;
            while (lbcu.hasNext())
            {
                lbcu.next();
                i++;
            }
            println("Name: " + next.getName() + ", count: " + i);
        }
```

Results I get:

```
NewScript.java> Name: CreateTypeInstance, count: 1
NewScript.java> Name: Deserialize, count: 1
```

This does not make any sense to me. The listing clearly show more instructions and I can see whole decompiled view yet API return some garbage?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a java env to check your code
before you edited you had a screenshot with a selection of a symbol in Namespaces
in SymbolTree

when you click such a symbol the listing window is synchronized to the Address of such Symbol
see screen shot
[image]

the following python script will print 10 instructions of this symbol
see if this is what you are looking for

```
import ghidra
ns = currentProgram.getSymbolTable().getNamespace(currentAddress)
cs = currentProgram.getListing().getCodeUnits(ns.body,True)
for i in range(0,10,1):
    print(cs.next())
```

executing this script will print as below compare with screen shot

```
codeunits4namespace.py> Running...
MOV EDI,EDI
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP,ESP
SUB ESP,0x10
PUSH EBX
PUSH ESI
MOV ESI,ECX
PUSH EDI
MOV EAX,dword ptr [ESI + 0x4]
PUSH dword ptr [EAX]
codeunits4namespace.py> Finished!
```

Comment: Yeah, your code is the same as mine but I get 1 instruction returned